# Shapefile and vector file don't precisely overlap when plotted

Tags: r, raster, rgdal

I want to plot a shapefile over a raster file in R but I can't make them overlap perfectly: the raster appears to be rotated of few degrees counter-clockwise. Is it a problem with the projection?

[image]

Please consider the following MWE

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal) 

# Download from http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/shp/ITA_adm.zip
shape_file = "ITA_adm1.shp"
# Download from http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v3-population-density/data-download
# Setting Geography: Country, Italy; Data Attributes: Grid
pop_density_file ="w001001.adf"

italy_map <- readOGR(dsn = shape_file, layer = "ITA_adm1")
italy_map_dens <- raster(pop_density_file)

colPal <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))( 500 )

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(italy_map_dens, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), axes=FALSE, box=FALSE, legend=FALSE, col=colPal)
plot(italy_map, xlim = c(6.70, 18.32), ylim = c(35.2, 47.6), border="grey", add=TRUE)
```

Comment: The population density data requires a registration and login. Ugh.

Comment: You can download without login. There's a button below login details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there was a bug in the `rgdal` package. My problem was solved after I updated it to version 0.8-12.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear to be a problem with the projection. You need to find out the exact projection of both datasets, and convert one of the datasets to the projection of the other dataset.

Comment: How do I find out their projection? If I open them in QGIS they overlap just fine...

Comment: Maybe in the QGis properties something is said regarding the projection? Otherwise, you need to get that information from the supplier of the data.

Comment: From the layer properties in QGIS they seem to have both the same CRS EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. I also tried to export them specify the CRS but still don't overlap.

Comment: They overlap perfectly for me - note its easier to see if you plot `italy_map_dens > 0` to get a two-colour raster. I'm not sure why you are plotting with xlim and ylim in both cases - it doesnt make sense to have xlim, ylim, and add=TRUE. Make sure you have the latest rgdal and also tell us which of the raster files you used - there's a few in the data set.